# retrofitting an induction cooktop into a 'commercial-style' gas cooktop opening

Tags: kitchens, stove, kitchen-counters

I have a commercial-style gas cooktop ([(ex)](https://www.kitchenaid.com/major-appliances/cooktops/gas-cooktops/gas-6-burner-cooktops/p.kitchenaid-36-6-burner-commercial-style-gas-rangetop.kcgc506jss.html)). The countertop surrounding it is granite and underneath is cabinetry.

The cutout it was installed on is illustrated in the manual:

[image: large cutout that removes all of granite from front and cabinet panel in the bottom]

What are my options for installing an induction cooktop? Is there anyway I can add a similar stainless steel enclosure somehow, so I don't have to buy another granite top?

Comment: What are the power requirements of the induction cooktop and what do you have available?

Comment: it would be a terrible waste to get a new granite top just for this new cooptop. Surely you can insert something in the existing opening. Have you already removed the gas cooktop or are you just planning for what it would take? No need to be in a hurry if the existing gas cooktop is working. An insert could be made from wood. Or get one made in a local architectural metal workshop.

Comment: We're in planning stages so am planning to upgrade to 220v

Comment: I have a ton of time and haven't removed anything. Seeing Mark's insert in action gives me home. I just wanted one more option other than buying a very rare rangetop induction cooktop instead.

Comment: Your writing "220v" is an indication that you need help in planning this. The modern power grid voltage is conventionally written 240 V and the actual voltage in many localities is between 240 V and 250 V.  There is curently a big rush to induction. My wife and I are now cooking on two 120 V induction countertop units placed on top of our 30-year-old GE electric stove.  You must have a highly capable gas cooktop. Do you do a lot of frying on a griddle? Or is this gas cooktop not really what you need?

Comment: It'd help if you showed us an *in situ* photo, rather than the manual instructions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar situation about ten years ago, replacing an old downdraft style electric stove with a new induction cooktop.  I made a wooden insert that fit into the existing countertop opening, with an open area sized for the induction cooktop.

[image]

[image]

It's not a perfect solution, but it solved the problem for us.  The same approach could be made from stainless steel or granite.

Comment: Thank you! This is nice to see in action.

Comment: Looks pretty! I'll just mention one thing for the OP though. My parents have solid wood work surfaces in their kitchen, and they're beautiful to look at, but avoiding water and heat damage is a continual PITA. The OP should be aware of that if they choose to use solid wood versus something more splash-proof and heat-proof like a moulded corian insert over wood bracing. (Which of course is more expensive than just wood, so you pays your money and you takes your choice.)

Comment: One benefit of induction is that there is very little waste heat. There should be a great reduction in the heating of the surface surround and of the cabinetry under the induction  cooktop. Traditionl gas cooktops generated a large amount of waste heat, and electric resistance cooktops generated enough waste heat to raise the temperature below the cooktop. .

Comment: @Mark There is still however some waste heat from cooling the induction circuitry. Do you have provision for air to flow through the space under the cooktop? You may have such a generous volume under the cooktop that this is unnecessary in your case, but storage space is prized in the ordinary kitchen. What is inside the space below the cooktop and what is its use? What is inside the double cabinet and what is its use?

Comment: @Mark Modern induction ranges (i.e., stove with cooktop and oven in one unit) have a long vent along the back. Much of this vent must be for the oven, but some of it must be to exhaust warm air heated by waste heat from the induction burners. Presumably air at ambient room temp is pulled into the space between the top of the oven and the bottom of the induction burners and pulled into the induction burners and then ejected at the top back of the stove.

Comment: @Mark what is the electric power setup for your induction cooktop? What wire size and breaker size? Is your cooktop plugged into a receptacle (e.g., a NEMA 14-50 4-wire) or is it hardwired? As I understnad it you formerly had a stove there so you must have had 120/240 V at 40 A or 50 A? Did you install a wall oven elsewhere in the kitchen. This is a beautiful setup you have. What brand of induction cooktop is this?

Comment: @JimStewart It's been quite a few years, and we've since moved, so I'm going from memory here.  I believe the instructions for the new cooktop specified a ventilation path in the front of the cabinet of a particular size.  I accommodated that because the wooden insert sits above the countertop.  Though you can't see it in the pictures, there is a gap between the bottom of the wood and the top of the cabinet at the front.  The cabinet was used for a few large pots, and had no shelves, so it was mostly empty space.  I never noticed it feeling warm inside.

Comment: @JimStewart There is a separate double electric oven in a cabinet to the right of the cooktop.  The previous cooktop was a GE downdraft electric cooktop on a 30 A circuit.  The new one is a Kitchenaid induction cooktop.  If I remember correctly it required a 40 A circuit, so I ran new 8 ga copper cable from the main panel to a metal box on the back wall under the cooktop.  It's hardwired from there.

Comment: @Mark is this a 36 inch wide cooktop or a 30 inch?

Comment: @JimStewart 36 inch.

Answer (score 4):

You cant easily add on bits of granite. And removing bits could fracture the rest. Your only hope is to find something that fits in the hole.

Just take the manual into the shop and measure the outside and the dimensions of the insert. Fortunately, most models come in reasonably standard formats.

If you can only find something smaller, talk to a granite installer. They maybe able to install a timber support and install strips on top. But seams will be visible and granite will not match.

Comment: Not matching would be fully acceptable to save the existing granite countertop. If possible don't cement it in place so that it could be removed if wanted.

Comment: Hey, yeah, the style of the existing cooktop is a big bulky rangetop that eats into the cabinetry. Induction cooktops in general don't come in that style except for two eu brands.