# How can I reduce the cutout in a granite counter top to support a smaller appliance?

Tags: stove, granite

I'm replacing a gas stovetop with an induction stovetop. It's going into a granite countertop, above two large drawers. My challenge is that the existing hole is a little larger than the hole the manufacturer specifies for the new cooktop.

The good news is that the new stovetop is wide enough to fully cover the hole, so I'm not worried about aesthetics. The bad news is that the existing hole is smaller than the recommended size and the stovetop vendor says installing as is will risk the glass breaking because it won't be sufficiently supported.

So my question to this group is what can I do to effective reduce the size of the hole in the granite countertop to better match the specification. I'm thinking add wood to the side, but how do I join it to the granite?

Here are the details of the existing hole in the granite.

|  | Width | Depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Existing (gas) | 35 1/4" | 19 3/16" |
| New (electric) | 34 1/4" | 19 7/16" |
| Difference | 1" | 1/4" |

Here are details on the new stovetop.

|  | Lip on stovetop |
| --- | --- |
| Left | 13/16" |
| Right | 13/16" |
| Front | 1/2" |
| Back | 1 5/16" |

Thanks.

Comment: Is it completely out of bounds to get a larger cooktop that will fit or might require making the hole bigger?

Comment: Also, model numbers and links to installation manuals for the old and new cooktops would help.

Comment: I'm confused: "the existing hole is a little larger than the hole the manufacturer specifies" yet, "the existing hole is smaller than the recommended size". Which is it?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/278723/retrofitting-an-induction-cooktop-into-a-commercial-style-gas-cooktop-opening

Comment: So for depth you actually need to go larger, not smaller as some seem to suggest in the answers.

Comment: The lip  on the back is 1-5/16". Are there openings on the back from air to flow out of the unit? Cooling air is usually pulled in from below and flows out on the side or back. You don't want to obstruct this flow. Leave clearance for air flow of about 1/2" to 13/16". Then leave a slit to the outside for heated air to flow out in back. Provide a slit in front for ambient air to flow in.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use wood, but steel angles or granite strips. The granite strips would be better, due to the different thermal expansion coefficient of steel.

An suitable 2-component glue should be enough to fix them.

Comment: Yes - granite counter top joints are commonly done with epoxy, and in this case you probably don't need to get someone who can make the joint nearly unnoticeable, since it will be hidden, so merely *functional* rather than *pretty* will do. For countertop joints out in the open it's usually worthwhile to hire someone with experience.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would use some 1"x1/2" metal bars (stainless or aluminum) on the sides of the cutout, and 1"x1/8" bars on the front and back.  Glue them (epoxy?) to the sides of the granite, and perhaps (carefully) drill some holes into the granite edge so you can epoxy some flathead machine screws in as dowels.

Comment: A better approach would be a frame out of metal T- stock or angle stock (steel, aluminum, brass, . . .) which hangs in the opening and so no epoxy or other adhesive required.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, if you took this approach how would you support the metal framing?

Comment: I cannot use a drawing program but I will try to use words. Assuming the cutout in the granite is slightly larger than required to support the lip (rim) of the cooktop make a rectangular frame out of flat metal stock of sufficient width that it will rest on the existing cutout and the inside dimensions are correct to support the lip of the cooktop--all around. On the underside you would have downward projections at least in the four corners that would keep the frame locked in place. Across the entire back there would be a vertical stiffener (making the flat bar into a T).

Comment: As linked to above https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/278752/62521

Comment: Making such a frame would require welding or brazing of some kind, no?  And would not be possible to install flush with the countertop.

Answer (score 1):

The cooktop generates heat below which you should consider dealing with by leaving a slit open at the back for heated air to rise out of. The cooktop has cooling fans which pull air in the bottom and expell it out the back or side underneath.  Ambient air could get into the space under the cooktop via a slit in front or other opening.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [company](https://summitappliance.com) that sells custom stainless steel trim kits or bezels for this specific purpose.

Comment: You should link directly to the kit you describe. A quick search on that site didn't turn it up.